# Is there a way to limit the size of a video file while uploading to firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Can I add some code to this ,so that the uploader won't exceed the video size limit?

```
final file =  await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
            StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("video").child(id);
            StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));
            var storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
            var downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            final String url = downloadUrl.toString();
            fb.child(id).set({
              "id": id,
              "link": url,
            }).then((value) {
              print("Done");
            });
          });
        } catch (error) {
          print(error);
        }
      }
```

Comment: You're not uploading to Firestore, but to Firebase Storage. While both products are part of Firebase, they are completely separate. I updated the tags on your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the filesize before upload:

```
final filesizeLimit = 999999;  // in bytes
final filesize = await file.length(); // in bytes
final isValidFilesize = filesize < filesizeLimit;
if (isValidFilesize) {
    // upload...
} else {
    // show message to the user that the file is too big
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's in bytes.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help with a code to compress the file before uploading?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have experience compressing files with Flutter/dart. Hope someone else will be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, videos are already compressed, no need to do that imho. Good luck!